# How do we make combinations of column values present in a dictionary of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

Let's say we have a dictionary of dataframes with 900 dataframes.

Each dataframe has unique number of rows but same number of column (let's say 9) and same column names. Lets say a column named "C1" common to all dataframes in the dictionary of dataframes has integer values varying from 1 to 4000.

How can we create a dataframe by selecting a row corresponding to any unique value in C1 from each dataframe in the dictionary of dataframes? The resulting dataframe will have 900 rows and same number of columns as the original dataframe (i.e., 9).

We don't want C1 values selected from each dataframe in the dictionary to be same. We want different combinations of values.

Not all dataframes have the same set of C1 values. Some might have `{11, 16, 20}`, others might have `{10, 16, 20}`. We only want to create dataframes from the values that exist across all dataframes. So in this example, we only want dataframes where C1 values are either `16` or `20`.

Can we also create possible combinations of such dataframes?

**Example:**

Let's say the dictionary of dataframe has four dataframes:

```
df1
C0  C1
a   1
a   2
a   3

df2
C0  C1
b   1
b   2
b   3

df3
C0  C1
c   1
c   2
c   3

df4
C0  C1
d   1
```

Example of few possible dataframes are given in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just choose the first row in each dataframe?  Do you want a row at random?  Or do you want rows where the C1 value is the same?

Comment: That was a typo. Rectified it. Thanks.

Comment: How many rows do you have in each dataframe?

Comment: It varies. One dataframe may have 1000 rows, other might have 1020 rows... so on

Comment: are the columns of the same type?  if so, consider making a single dataframe then doing `groupby` and `sample`

Comment: `selecting a row corresponding to any unique value in C1 from each dataframe in the dictionary of dataframes?`  Do you mean, that you want to get the row e.g. `C1 = 22` from each df, or a different value in C1 for each df?

Comment: @TimRoberts I want to make dataframes for possible combinations of values in C1 in each dataframe in the dictionary of dataframes. So, I don't want to fix on 1 or random row selection

Comment: @anon01 a different value in C1 for each df?

Comment: @vp_050 I think the only way to provide enough clarity is to show an example of the input (dict of example dfs) and expected output

Comment: "We only want to create dataframes from the values that exist across **all** dataframes.". So your outcome is false. Only the first output dataframe is right (all 1), now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# Setup
cols = [f"C{i}" for i in range(10)]
dfs = {i: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 4000, (1500, 10)), columns=cols)
           for i in range(900)}

excluded = []
data = []
for df in dfs.values():
    row = df.loc[~df['C0'].isin(excluded)].sample(n=1)
    excluded.append(row['C0'].squeeze())
    data.append(row)
df = pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df.head()
     C0    C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8    C9
0   430  1022  2094   345  1958   256  2142  3931  1030   800
1  3082   606  2657  2038   950   663  3037  1768  2471  2017
2  3075  2543  3046   790   588  1476  2562  2249  1457  1549
3  1636  3273  1585  1099   547   630  1958  3396  2110   117
4  3798  3933  2649  2234  3685  3509  3051  1970  1543  3685

>>> df['C0'].nunique()
900

>>> df.shape
(900, 10)

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 900 entries, 1 to 1499
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   C0      900 non-null    int64
 1   C1      900 non-null    int64
 2   C2      900 non-null    int64
 3   C3      900 non-null    int64
 4   C4      900 non-null    int64
 5   C5      900 non-null    int64
 6   C6      900 non-null    int64
 7   C7      900 non-null    int64
 8   C8      900 non-null    int64
 9   C9      900 non-null    int64
dtypes: int64(10)
memory usage: 77.3 KB
```

**Erratum**: I used `C0` as name instead of `C1`.

Comment: @vp_050. Is it what you expect?

Comment: I need few more minutes to check the output. Thank you.

Comment: I am not getting proper result. what is (1500, 10)? Also the values in C1 cannot be random. What if the random number generated does not exist in C1 in any one of the dataframe?

Comment: 1500 is for simulate some rows, 10 columns. `sample` extract a row from the current dataframe so this number always exist. At each iteration, this number is appended to the excluded list to avoid duplicate numbers.